# Custom Validation in dynamic Form against array of item

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

I have a Person[] which can be edited dynamically, one at a time, so I have a the following:

```
<template ngFor let-indx="index" let-persons [ngForOf]="persons">
    <div *ngIf="!person.isEditing">
        <h4>{{person.name}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="person.isEditing">
        <form #addNewGuestForm="ngForm" novalidate>
            <input [(ngModel)]="person.name" #personName="ngModel" required maxlength="50" minlength="2">
        </form>
    </div>
    <button (click)="person.isEditing=!person.isEditing">Edit/Save</button>
</template>
```

**Note:** the form is wrapped by a *ngIf.

*Question:* how do I validate the name is unique and doesnt collide with other names in the persons array? I tried doing the following, but I get the classic: `Can't bind to 'persons' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[uniqueValidator][ngModelGroup]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UniqueValidator, multi: true }]
})
export class UniqueValidator implements Validator {
    @Input() persons: Person[];
    validate(control: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } {
        //validation against other items in persons
    }
}
```

and the html changed into:

```
<input uniqueValidator [persons]="persons" [(ngModel)]="person.name" #personName="ngModel" required maxlength="50" minlength="2">
```

**Note:** I have included the `UniqueValidator` in the `@NgModule`'s `declarations` section.

Comment: I don't see `ngModelGroup` in your html

Comment: yup! just now figured it out :) silly me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selector was the culprit, changing it to

```
selector: '[uniqueValidator][ngModel]'
```

worked !